# merging rows with repeating column values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
              data
    0          a
    1          a
    2          a
    3          a
    4          a 
    5          b
    6          b
    7          b
    8          b
    9          b
```

I want to group the repeating values of a and b into a single row element as follows:

```
         data
   0      a
          a
          a
          a
          a
    1     b
          b
          b
          b
          b
```

How do I go about doing this? I tried the following but it puts each repeating value in its own column

```
     df.groupby('data')
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, you still have just as many rows in the second, it just looks like you want to change the index?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, it looks like you need to define a new column using `filter` or `np.where` and set it to 0 for 'a' and 1 for 'b', then use `groupby` on that column. Right now, it's grouping by the index, which has different values for each row.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a `pivot` problem, but since you missing the column(create by `cumcount`) and index(create by `factorize`) columns , it is hard to figure out

```
pd.crosstab(pd.factorize(df.data)[0],df.groupby('data').cumcount(),df.data,aggfunc='sum')
Out[358]: 
col_0  0  1  2  3  4
row_0               
0      a  a  a  a  a
1      b  b  b  b  b
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
index = ((df['data'] != df['data'].shift()).cumsum() - 1).rename(columns= {'data':''})

df = df.set_index(index)

    data
0   a
0   a
0   a
0   a
0   a
1   b
1   b
1   b
1   b
1   b
```

​

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.factorize` followed by `set_index`:

```
df = df.assign(key=pd.factorize(df['data'], sort=False)[0]).set_index('key')

print(df)

    data
key     
0      a
0      a
0      a
0      a
0      a
1      b
1      b
1      b
1      b
1      b
```